# chromium not render page when some resources unloaded for network error

Tags: chromium, webkit

I encounter some awkward problems using chromium(version  33.0.1750.149 (255236)).

How to reproduce problem:

1. open [github page](https://github.com/h5bp/html5-boilerplate/blob/v4.3.0/doc/TOC.md)
2. some img fail to load with reason **net::ERR_TIMED_OUT**

The page stay blank until i click the **STOP** button on the top left status bar.

It may be the render engine do not render a page to the screen until the resources all be loaded.

Any suggestion?

Comment: I'm able to load the page, and watching the network traffic I'm seeing a mix of 304 and 200 status codes which all look right to me. I'm using version 33.0.1750.154 m. Could there be another factor in play?

Comment: I do not know why the [resource](https://github.global.ssl.fastly.net/assets/frameworks-4ffe0645461d6fd51485ee3e555a732ee7075743.js) takes me about 5min.Though, the point is that the chromium do not render the page while waiting for the resource. Some chance is the problem with the github page design? @JasonAller. Thx for the comment.